# Functor laws checking with QuickCheck-classes library

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor, quickcheck

I want to check functor laws for instance:

```
instance Functor Stream where
    fmap f (x :> xs) = (f x) :> fmap f xs
```

where Stream is

```
data Stream a = a :> Stream a
```

I use QuickCheck.Classes (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/quickcheck-classes) to check the laws but I have some problem. When I try to run

```
lawsCheck (functorLaws (Proxy :: Proxy (Stream Int)))
```

I get the following:

```
* Couldn't match kind `*' with `* -> *'
      When matching types
        proxy0 :: (* -> *) -> *
        Proxy :: * -> *
      Expected: proxy0 f0
        Actual: Proxy (Stream Int)
    * In the first argument of `functorLaws', namely
        `(Proxy :: Proxy (Stream Int))'
      In the first argument of `lawsCheck', namely
        `(functorLaws (Proxy :: Proxy (Stream Int)))'
      In the expression:
        lawsCheck (functorLaws (Proxy :: Proxy (Stream Int)))
```

What is "proxy0 f0"? Is there any way to fix this error? I can't understand why this code is not being executed.

Comment: You need to pass a `Proxy Stream`, not a `Proxy (Stream Int)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @leftaroundabout commented, `functorLaws` takes the *unapplied* functor, with kind `* -> *`. The correct version of your code would be:

```
lawsCheck (functorLaws (Proxy :: Proxy Stream))
```